# How can I fix "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)"

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

From the controller, I call my service Spring "facturationSvc" which performs a time-consuming processing and returns an object list.

After a few seconds I recieve the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)".

How can I fix it?

```
        vm.afficher = function() {

            vm.details = [];

            var x = vm.applicationField;
            if (x === undefined || x === null) {
                x = 'off';
            }

            FacturationSvc.generate({
                selectedDt : new Date(vm.selectedDt),
                applicationField : x
            }).$promise.then(function(resp) {
                vm.details = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp));
                vm.table.check = true;
            });
        }
```

The Angular méthod service:

```
svc.generate = $resource(svc.url + '/generate/:selectedDt/applicationName/:applicationField', {}, {
        'get':  {method:'GET', isArray:true, cache: true}
    }).get;
```

Comment: why did you put `.get` at the last of the function, please elaborate

Comment: for get to this resource in my controller spring :

@RequestMapping(value = "/generate/{selectedDt}/applicationName/{applicationField}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public List<Facturation> generate(@PathVariable final Date selectedDt,@PathVariable final String applicationField){
  return facturationSvc.facturer(selectedDt,applicationField);
 }